# Connecting an old computer to wifi configuration

Tags: wifi-configuration

I am working in Ethiopia and have an old laptop (Dell Latiude C540/640) with a wireless network adapter (Netgear 802.11b MA521). The Dell is running Windows XP Pro service pack 3 (clean).

When I try to connect the wifi router I get the message it often requests the WEP key. I have the wifi password but I from what I understand the WEP key is different. I have looked at the back of the router and can see no WEP key. I do not have the router username/password.

[image]

Authenticaton/Encryption options are:

Open : Disabled/WEP;
Shared : Disabled/WEP; 
WPA: TKIP/AES; 
WPA-PSK : TKIP/AES

On most settings I get the 'Acquiring network address' message but it then reverts back to Automatic.

However on WPA-PSK : TKIP it says I am connected it seems I am ony connected to the router and I cannot go beyond it. I can see the router login page but cannot browse and ping etc.

[image]

Any ideas what I can try to get this thing connected if it is even possible?

Comment: Connecting at a hotel usually requires you to got to the hotel's home page and to log in there... keep that page open while browsing.

Comment: You would think so but here it is open with no login page. I have managed to connect using Tkip and can access any http page but not https. So now trying to figure out why that is. Presumably an encryption issue.

Comment: BTW, hotel is using WPA2, not old WPA...see https://www.uc.edu/content/dam/uc/ucit/docs/nts/WPA2%20INSTRUCTIONS.pdf

Comment: Very useful. WPA2 is not available as an option. I will see if I can get it. I presume that this is a driver issue rather than XP

Comment: BTW, if the PC is too old to run a modern Windows version, you might find Linux distros are more up-to-date. Both 32- and 64-bit version of Ubuntu, for example, are available through v. 18.04 LTS (though that version, only *via* update from an older 32-bit installation).

Comment: Its a hardware issue, it will never support WPA2. Buy a cheap usb wifi dongle that supports WPA2 if you can.